# How to overwrite previous text in center of screen

Tags: python

I want to print to the center of the terminal and am using:

```
import shutil

columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
print("hello world".center(columns))
```

Later on I want to overwrite the text with:

```
print("hell world".center(columns))
```

That is the new text should completely replace the old text.

How can you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use print with `end` and `flush` parameters

```py
print("hello world".center(columns), end="\r", flush=True)
```

Here is a quick example

```py
import shutil
from time import sleep

columns = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
print("hello world".center(columns), end="\r", flush=True)
sleep(1)
print("This is a test run".center(columns))
print("The previous line was overwritten")
```

Comment: That is great. Thank you!